# Player rotating along wrong axis?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I have a character that is essentially a sphere, but scaled at y1, x1.2, z1 (a spheroid).

I can apply force to the object in any given 'pushDirection', which is a product of the character's rigidbody position minus the main camera transform position (this works fine to move the character in the direction the camera is facing – 'forwards' in my game should always be in the direction the camera is facing).

But now I'm trying to make the object *rotate* forwards – in the direction the camera is facing – instead of adding force. I'm adding torque instead. [Here's a rough illustrated screenshot of my goal with my intended axis:

[image]

Note that whenever the camera rotates around the object, the axis for rotation will shift.

Instead though, I'm getting a result where the character rotates as is shown in this illustrated screenshot:

[image]

As mentioned, as the camera moves the axis for rotation shifts along with the camera. But I want the object to move away from the camera rather than rotate to the left. (Note, in both screenshots I had the object suspended without gravity to try and debug its rotation).

Relevant bits of my script are below:

```html
void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        pushForward =  rb.transform.position -
        Camera.main.transform.position;
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        speed = rb.velocity.magnitude;
        pushForward =  rb.transform.position - Camera.main.transform.position;
 
        if (Input.GetKey("w"))
        {
            isForward = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isForward = false;
        }
    }
 
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // IF KEY IS DOWN, MOVE //
        if (isForward == true)
        {
            float turn = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            rb.AddTorque(pushForward * torque * turn);
            Debug.Log("Moving Forward");
        }
    }
```

I've played around with this so much I just can't get my head around it. I'm also totally confused as if I change the Input.GetAxis to "Horizontal", the debug message "Moving Forward" pops up fine but I don't get any sort of rotation in the object – none at all.

If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it, i've gotten myself a bit confused.

Comment: what is torque in your code?

Comment: @DávidFlorek `torque` is a `float` used to increase/decrease the amount of rotation per input unit.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, in order to obtain the rotation you want, you need to cross multiply `pushForward` with `Vector3.down`.

I.E.:

```
void FixedUpdate() {
    // IF KEY IS DOWN, MOVE //
    if (isForward == true) {
        var vect = Vector3.Cross(pushForward, Vector3.down);
        float turn = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        rb.AddTorque(vect * torque * turn);
        Debug.Log("Moving Forward");
    }
}
```